# Erlang build error: No native ethread implementation found

Tags: windows, erlang, cygwin, couchdb

I have installed VS Community 2013 x86 + Cygwin and I'm been following the instructions to build a 32bit version of erlang.

When I execute `./opt_build boot -a`, I get the following error:

> ./include/internal/ethread.h:381:2: error: #error "No native ethread implementation found. If you want to use fallbacks you have to disable native ethread support with configure."
>    #error "No native ethread implementation found. If you want to use fallbacks you have to disable native ethread support with configure."

Anyone has ever see this error? What are the impacts of disabling ethread?

More logs:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.3.9600.17336
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

 EMU_CC obj/win32/opt/smp/beam_emu.o
In file included from beam/erl_threads.h:265:0,
                 from beam/erl_smp.h:28,
                 from beam/sys.h:491,
                 from beam/beam_emu.c:26:
../include/internal/ethread.h:381:2: error: #error "No native ethread implementation found. If you want to use fallbacks you have to disable native ethread support with configure."
 #error "No native ethread implementation found. If you want to use fallbacks you have to disable native ethread support with configure."
  ^~~~~
In file included from beam/beam_load.h:25:0,
                 from beam/export.h:81,
                 from beam/global.h:33,
                 from beam/beam_emu.c:28:
beam/erl_process.h: In function 'erts_get_runq_proc':
beam/erl_process.h:2159:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     return (ErtsRunQueue *) erts_atomic_read_nob(&p->run_queue);
            ^
In file included from beam/erl_process.h:2347:0,
                 from beam/beam_load.h:25,
                 from beam/export.h:81,
                 from beam/global.h:33,
                 from beam/beam_emu.c:28:
beam/erl_process_lock.h: In function 'erts_pix2proc':
beam/erl_process_lock.h:939:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     proc = (Process *) erts_ptab_pix2intptr_nob(&erts_proc, ix);
            ^
beam/erl_process_lock.h: In function 'erts_proc_lookup_raw':
beam/erl_process_lock.h:952:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     proc = (Process *) erts_ptab_pix2intptr_ddrb(&erts_proc,
            ^
In file included from beam/erl_port.h:30:0,
                 from beam/global.h:44,
                 from beam/beam_emu.c:28:
beam/erl_port_task.h: In function 'erts_port_task_handle_init':
beam/erl_port_task.h:154:36: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
     erts_smp_atomic_init_nob(pthp, (erts_aint_t) NULL);
                                    ^
beam/erl_port_task.h: In function 'erts_port_task_is_scheduled':
beam/erl_port_task.h:160:13: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     return ((void *) erts_smp_atomic_read_acqb(pthp)) != NULL;
             ^
In file included from beam/global.h:44:0,
                 from beam/beam_emu.c:28:
beam/erl_port.h: In function 'erts_port_runq':
beam/erl_port.h:221:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     rq1 = (ErtsRunQueue *) erts_smp_atomic_read_nob(&prt->run_queue);
           ^
beam/erl_port.h:226:8: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
  rq2 = (ErtsRunQueue *) erts_smp_atomic_read_nob(&prt->run_queue);
        ^
beam/erl_port.h: In function 'erts_pix2port':
beam/erl_port.h:475:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     prt = (Port *) erts_ptab_pix2intptr_nob(&erts_port, ix);
           ^
beam/erl_port.h: In function 'erts_port_lookup_raw':
beam/erl_port.h:489:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     prt = (Port *) erts_ptab_pix2intptr_ddrb(&erts_port,
           ^
beam/erl_port.h: In function 'erts_id2port':
beam/erl_port.h:518:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     prt = (Port *) erts_ptab_pix2intptr_ddrb(&erts_port,
           ^
beam/erl_port.h: In function 'erts_id2port_sflgs':
beam/erl_port.h:552:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     prt = (Port *) erts_ptab_pix2intptr_ddrb(&erts_port,
           ^
beam/erl_port.h: In function 'erts_thr_id2port_sflgs':
beam/erl_port.h:611:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     prt = (Port *) erts_ptab_pix2intptr_ddrb(&erts_port,
           ^
beam/beam_emu.c: In function 'process_main':
beam/beam_emu.c:768:17: warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
       if ((_res >> (8*sizeof(Uint))) != 0) { Fail; } \
                 ^
beam/beam_emu.c:4068:7: note: in expansion of macro 'BsSafeMul'
       BsSafeMul(Arg2, Unit, goto system_limit, tmp_arg1);
       ^~~~~~~~~
beam/beam_emu.c:768:17: warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
       if ((_res >> (8*sizeof(Uint))) != 0) { Fail; } \
                 ^
beam/beam_emu.c:4129:3: note: in expansion of macro 'BsSafeMul'
   BsSafeMul(b, Unit, goto system_limit, c);
   ^~~~~~~~~
beam/beam_emu.c:768:17: warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
       if ((_res >> (8*sizeof(Uint))) != 0) { Fail; } \
                 ^
beam/beam_emu.c:784:7: note: in expansion of macro 'BsSafeMul'
       BsSafeMul(_uint_size, Unit, Fail, Target); \
       ^~~~~~~~~
beam/beam_emu.c:4649:6: note: in expansion of macro 'BsGetFieldSize'
      BsGetFieldSize(tmp_arg2, (flags >> 3), ClauseFail(), size);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
beam/beam_emu.c:768:17: warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
       if ((_res >> (8*sizeof(Uint))) != 0) { Fail; } \
                 ^
beam/beam_emu.c:784:7: note: in expansion of macro 'BsSafeMul'
       BsSafeMul(_uint_size, Unit, Fail, Target); \
       ^~~~~~~~~
beam/beam_emu.c:835:5: note: in expansion of macro 'BsGetFieldSize'
     BsGetFieldSize(Sz, ((Flags) >> 3), Fail, _size);  \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
win32/opt/smp/beam_cold.h:12:5: note: in expansion of macro 'BsGetBinary_2'
     BsGetBinary_2(r(0), Arg(1), targ1, Arg(3), dst, StoreResult, ClauseFail());
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
beam/beam_emu.c:768:17: warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
       if ((_res >> (8*sizeof(Uint))) != 0) { Fail; } \
                 ^
beam/beam_emu.c:784:7: note: in expansion of macro 'BsSafeMul'
       BsSafeMul(_uint_size, Unit, Fail, Target); \
       ^~~~~~~~~
beam/beam_emu.c:835:5: note: in expansion of macro 'BsGetFieldSize'
     BsGetFieldSize(Sz, ((Flags) >> 3), Fail, _size);  \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
win32/opt/smp/beam_cold.h:22:5: note: in expansion of macro 'BsGetBinary_2'
     BsGetBinary_2(xb(Arg(1)), Arg(2), targ1, Arg(4), dst, StoreResult, ClauseFail());
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
beam/beam_emu.c:768:17: warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
       if ((_res >> (8*sizeof(Uint))) != 0) { Fail; } \
                 ^
beam/beam_emu.c:784:7: note: in expansion of macro 'BsSafeMul'
       BsSafeMul(_uint_size, Unit, Fail, Target); \
       ^~~~~~~~~
beam/beam_emu.c:870:4: note: in expansion of macro 'BsGetFieldSize'
    BsGetFieldSize(Bits, Unit, Fail, _size);   \
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
win32/opt/smp/beam_cold.h:86:5: note: in expansion of macro 'BsSkipBits2'
     BsSkipBits2(r(0), xb(Arg(1)), Arg(2), ClauseFail());
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
beam/beam_emu.c:768:17: warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
       if ((_res >> (8*sizeof(Uint))) != 0) { Fail; } \
                 ^
beam/beam_emu.c:784:7: note: in expansion of macro 'BsSafeMul'
       BsSafeMul(_uint_size, Unit, Fail, Target); \
       ^~~~~~~~~
beam/beam_emu.c:870:4: note: in expansion of macro 'BsGetFieldSize'
    BsGetFieldSize(Bits, Unit, Fail, _size);   \
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
win32/opt/smp/beam_cold.h:94:5: note: in expansion of macro 'BsSkipBits2'
     BsSkipBits2(r(0), yb(Arg(1)), Arg(2), ClauseFail());
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
beam/beam_emu.c:768:17: warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
       if ((_res >> (8*sizeof(Uint))) != 0) { Fail; } \
                 ^
beam/beam_emu.c:784:7: note: in expansion of macro 'BsSafeMul'
       BsSafeMul(_uint_size, Unit, Fail, Target); \
       ^~~~~~~~~
beam/beam_emu.c:870:4: note: in expansion of macro 'BsGetFieldSize'
    BsGetFieldSize(Bits, Unit, Fail, _size);   \
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
win32/opt/smp/beam_cold.h:102:5: note: in expansion of macro 'BsSkipBits2'
     BsSkipBits2(xb(Arg(1)), r(0), Arg(2), ClauseFail());
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
beam/beam_emu.c:768:17: warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
       if ((_res >> (8*sizeof(Uint))) != 0) { Fail; } \
                 ^
beam/beam_emu.c:784:7: note: in expansion of macro 'BsSafeMul'
       BsSafeMul(_uint_size, Unit, Fail, Target); \
       ^~~~~~~~~
beam/beam_emu.c:870:4: note: in expansion of macro 'BsGetFieldSize'
    BsGetFieldSize(Bits, Unit, Fail, _size);   \
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
win32/opt/smp/beam_cold.h:110:5: note: in expansion of macro 'BsSkipBits2'
     BsSkipBits2(xb(Arg(1)), xb(Arg(2)), Arg(3), ClauseFail());
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
beam/beam_emu.c:768:17: warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
       if ((_res >> (8*sizeof(Uint))) != 0) { Fail; } \
                 ^
beam/beam_emu.c:784:7: note: in expansion of macro 'BsSafeMul'
       BsSafeMul(_uint_size, Unit, Fail, Target); \
       ^~~~~~~~~
beam/beam_emu.c:870:4: note: in expansion of macro 'BsGetFieldSize'
    BsGetFieldSize(Bits, Unit, Fail, _size);   \
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
win32/opt/smp/beam_cold.h:118:5: note: in expansion of macro 'BsSkipBits2'
     BsSkipBits2(xb(Arg(1)), yb(Arg(2)), Arg(3), ClauseFail());
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
make[3]: *** [win32/Makefile:672: obj/win32/opt/smp/beam_emu.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/werl/otp_src_18.3/erts/emulator'
make[2]: *** [/cygdrive/c/werl/otp_src_18.3/make/run_make.mk:35: opt] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/werl/otp_src_18.3/erts/emulator'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:61: smp] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/werl/otp_src_18.3/erts'
make: *** [Makefile:444: emulator] Error 2
```

Comment: For building on cygwin you need to use the cygwin compilers. Otherwise it is better to use mingw tools.

Comment: According to the [official installation guide](http://erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL-WIN32.html#id74846), I can use cygwin or mingw tools. Altough, only one file will be compile by these tools. The other are compiled with Visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was missing some Cygwin dependencies. I checked everything from Devel and removed anything not related to C compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the instructions in the [official installation guide](http://erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL-WIN32.html#id74846)?

I suppose you have all the deps already installed (I'm more familiar with MinGW/MSYS but it should build just fine with Cygwin).

Note that you should run the following command:

```
./otp_build env_win32 # x64 <- add this for 64bit build
```

Comment: Yeah I did the following. I am trying to build CouchDB in 32bit instead of 64bit. I adapted their instructions here: https://github.com/popojargo/couchdb-glazier/blob/win32/INSTALL_32.md

Comment: From the [code](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/b873e5cd6d78191d303c7c828ab7df7cd7fdf4d2/erts/include/internal/ethread.h#L393), the only path for this to happen is if the variable `ETHR_WIN32_THREADS` is not defined. And it should be defined in the config from [aclocal](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/21754c8d402855af5081dad0aff465a8f0f7eda7/erts/aclocal.m4#L1567)

Comment: In the configure step, I see this log: `checking for native win32 threads... yes`

Comment: It looks to me as a bug in the build process. You should probably fill a bug report. Sorry I can't help you more than that :)

Comment: For Cygwin you should prefer to use pthreads.  This is something that should be detected by Erlang's configure process.